# как вывести все категории товаров в sidebar

Tags: html5, django, python-3.6, jinja2

при попытке вывести все категории товаров в sidebar на основной стронице они появляются. но при переходе на страницу с описанием одного конкретного товара в списке категорий остается только категории 'All'. а остальные пропадают. помогите пожалуйста разобраться в том, что приводит к такому поведению.

вот мои шаблоны:

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>{% block title %}My shop{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Shop</a>
    <div id="subheader">
        <div class="cart">
            {% with total_items=cart|length %}
                {% if cart|length > 0 %}
                    Your cart:
                    <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_detail' %}">
                        {{ total_items }} item{{ total_items|pluralize }},
                        ${{ cart.get_total_price }}
                    </a>
                {% else %}
                    Your cart is empty.
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-lg-3">
            <h3>Authentication</h3>
            <ul>
                {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <ul>
                <li {% if not category %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}">All</a>
                </li>
                {% for c in categories %}
                    <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="main" class="product-list col-lg-9">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages%}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

product_detail.html

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.title }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="product-detail row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
            <h2><a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.category }}</a></h2>
            <p class="price">${{ product.price }}</p>
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                {{ cart_product_form }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
            </form>
            {{ product.description|linebreaks }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

product_list.html

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}</h1>
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}

            <div class="item col-lg-3">
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}" alt="...">
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a><br>
                    ${{ product.price }}
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}


def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})


def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)

    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product,
                   'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```

Comment: Ну а почему они там должны отображаться? Ты передаешь `products` в `product_list.html` и там циклом его перебираешь. А в `product_detail.html` этого не нет...

Comment: циклом for я перебираю товары, а категории находятся внутри if. моя задача заключается в том чтобы в product_detail.html выводились в sidebar все существующие категории

Comment: а `categories` передал в `product_detail`?

Comment: категории наследуются из base.html

Comment: Покажи представления свои.

Comment: добавил в вопрос и вьюшки

Comment: ну и где ты передаёшь категории в шаблон?

Comment: понял вашу мысль, но попытки ее реализовать закончились еще более незнакомыми ошибками. укажите пожалуйста куда/в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0):

добавление categories = Category.objects.all() в product_detail решает мой вопрос.
как я понял, без этой строки (даже если в шаблоне есть попытка отобразить категории)
django не поймет что нужно вывести в шаблоне. если я не прав поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Comment: Всё верно поняли.